# How to count occurrence of each unique ID in each bin in a 2D histogram (python or pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file and I would like to create a 2d histogram where the value in each bin depends on the unique ID. For example (see below), for the range 0<x<1 and 1<y<2, the value is 2 (A, B) not 3 (A, A, B) because A appears twice. Thanks!

| ID | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0.5 | 1.4 |
| A | 0.6 | 1.6 |
| A | 1.2 | 2.2 |
| B | 0.7 | 1.7 |
| C | 4.4 | 3.5 |
| C | 3.1 | 3.7 |

Comment: What if there are multiple ids in an interval? And what is the size of your interval? Please post the desired output.

Comment: In this example, I would like 0<x<1,1<y<2: 2 unique IDs   , 1<x<2 and 2<y<3: 1 unique ID  , 3<x<4 and 3<y<4: 1 unique ID, 4<x<5 and 3<y<4: 1 unique ID. Rest ranges are all 0.

Comment: What if there are multiple ids in an interval?

Comment: So I only want to count the number of the unique ID in an interval, and plot those numbers of the unique ID in the hist2D . I just wonder if there is an easy way rather than going through loop/if.

Comment: But in question you are saying for range 0<x<1, 1<y<2 value is 2 because A appears twice. But if you are counting unique ids then you should count A once only.

Comment: No, it's 2 because A and B. There are 3 IDs (A,A,B) but two unique IDs (A and B).

Comment: I have added an answer. I was busy at work hence the delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bin of `i_x < x < j_x`, `i_y < y < j_y`  can be uniquely identified as the `(i_x, i_y)`; we can see that this tuple is unique for each bin. `i_x` and `i_y` are simply the floor value of `x` and `y`. Like For row : `(x, y) = (0.5, 1.4)` bin is: `0 < 0.5 < 1`, `1 < 1.4 < 1.2` here `i_x = 0 = floor(0.5)` and `i_y = 1 = floor(1.4)`.

Approach:

1. Find `i_x` and `i_y` for x and y columns.
2. Group the dataframe using key `(i_x, i_y)` and count unique `IDs` in each of the group.

Code:

```
>>> df
  ID    x    y
0  A  0.5  1.4
1  A  0.6  1.6
2  A  1.2  2.2
3  B  0.7  1.7
4  C  4.4  3.5
5  C  3.1  3.7

df['bin_x'] = np.floor(df.x).astype(int)
df['bin_y'] = np.floor(df.y).astype(int)
df = (df.groupby(['bin_x', 'bin_y'], as_index = False)['ID']
        .agg({'cnt' : 'nunique'}))


>>> df
   bin_x  bin_y  cnt
0      0      1    2
1      1      2    1
2      3      3    1
3      4      3    1
```

If you are defining your histogram as numpy array of size (5, 5) then we can assign `cnt` values to that array and get the desired histogram.

```
histogram = np.zeros((5, 5))
histogram[df.bin_x, df.bin_y] = df.cnt
>>> histogram
array([[0., 2., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```